# Eclipse Minecraft Error Working directory does not exist

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have looked everywhere for an answer to this question but have not found anything. Basically I've got Minecraft 1.8 open in eclipse but when I press the green play button it says 'Error: Working directory does not exist.' When I went into my forge folder and added a folder called 'run' where it said it was missing the error goes away and another error appears saying 'Error: Could not find or load main class GradleStart.' Please help!

Comment: have you gone to the directory itself in your shell and typed gradlew setupDecompWorkspace -eclipse ? and set your eclipse to the eclipse folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem while beginning modding for Minecraft.

To do this, go to your `Run Configurations` and type in the following for the VM Arguments: `-Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M`.

That should make Minecraft run correctly. I hope to see your mod later in the minecraftforge webpage.

Comment: My problem was I moved my files and it was still trying to run from my old folder. Run configurations helped because I figured out I could change Run -> Run configurations -> Argument. Thanks!